Index display is not showing in TabView
I have a pretty simple TabView. The .tabViewStyle is .page. It is my understanding that for this style the index indicator is supposed to show up at the bottom–which is currently not the case.
Here's the view:
struct PageView: View {
    @State private var selectedPage = 0
    let items: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                    .tabItem {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                    .tag(item)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Learning")
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}

#Preview {
    NavigationStack {
        PageView(
            items: [
                "Foo", "Bar", "Buzz"
            ]
        )
            .navigationTitle("Page View")
    }
}

The "page" part of the view is working–meaning that I can swipe right to get to the next page and left to the previous, but because the expected dots are missing I have no clue as to how many pages there are in total and as to where I am in the array of pages.
What am I missing here?


It is not visible because the background is white, and the index display is also white.

The page indicators are always white, with different degrees of opacity. They can only be seen if the background is not white. See also TabView indicator disappears

Note, typically, TabView should not be inside a NavigationStack, it should be
the top container. Re-structure your code.

Oh my … Thanks, that helps.

Also–note to self (or others that are going to find this down the road): tinting the dots in another color is possible by dropping down to UIKit (see here)
